# Local Notifications not firing when scheduled from a BGProcessingTask?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter, bgprocessingtask

I've tested this a number of ways and my `BGProcessingTask` works fine for printing anything to the console so I'm sure it's scheduling the local notification.  And scheduling the local notification from the app itself works fine and fires, however I cannot get the local notification to ever fire from the BGProcessingTask.  Is this a bug?  It should work as expected one would think?

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/gesabo/b00784b2acb9a56bb443b047ddefe5b7) of my code since it's too much to paste.